# How to parse the result that is returned for FileReader using Blobs to base64

Tags: javascript, blob, filereader

I am working with javascript FileReader()

I am taking a blob and reading it in to convert to base64 string.

Everything is working except it gives the result as a full string.

I've added a simple .replace() to fix the issue right now, but curious if there is a better way?

```
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.data);

        reader.onloadend = function () {

            base64data = reader.result;

            var base64 = reader.result.replace('data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,', '');

        };
```

As you can see from the code above, the result is set to data: and base64,

after base64, the base64 string is located.

I would like to not have to do a .replace() on some static text (that could changed based on the way I'm am obtaining the blob: e.data.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Appears there are NO commas in base64 string so I can just split on the only comma in the string and take the index 1:

```
var base64String = reader.result.split(',')[1];
```